# AWS cli unable to list s3 content when using --color parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I installed the aws cli. My version is 2.0.5 in ubuntu. when issuing

```
aws s3 ls --color on
```

it complains that --color needs at least one argument. If I remove the `--color` tag - it complains that `--color` is required. has somebody else run into that issue?
Thanks

Comment: Seems to work fine with `aws-cli/2.0.53 Python/3.8.5` (on Mac).  If you run `aws s3 ls --color` then it complains "error: argument --color: expected one argument". If you specify `on` without `--color` then the invocation attempts to list the bucket called `on` (resulting in InvalidBucketName). If you simply run `aws s3 ls` it will list all your buckets.

Answer (score 0):

The `--color` parameter is used to control color output. For example:

```
aws s3api list-buckets --output table --color off
```

Not all commands use color. (`aws s3 ls` does not use colors.)

Typically, there should be no need to specify this parameter.